# Who does the conversion on copy/paste?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Suppose I have an input field in a web page with charset `UTF8`; suppose I open a text file encoded with `ISO-8859-1` as charset.

Now I copy and paste a string with special characters (like, for example, `ô`) from file to the input field : I see that the special characters is correctly displayed into input field.

Who does the conversion from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF8`? The browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the file and copy/paste it to the browser, it ends up in Unicode, as that is what the browser's UI controls use internally.  Who actually performs the conversion from ISO-8859-1 to Unicode depends on a few factors (what OS you are using, whether your chosen text editor is compiled to use Ansi or Unicode, what clipboard format(s) - `CF_TEXT` for Ansi, `CF_UNICODETEXT` for Unicode - the app uses for the copy, etc).  But either way, when the web browser submits the form, it then encodes its Unicode data to the charset of the HTML/form during transmission.

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood, it's not really converted to UTF-8, but instead to the internal representation of characters used by the browser, which is quite likely to be UTF-16 (no matter what the encoding of the web page is).

Comment: This.  But note that if you need UTF-8, you can specify acceptable charsets.  `<form action="file.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">`.  I'm not sure if that alters the browser's internal character set when the user is editing it, but it will ensure that UTF-8 data is sent to the server (in compliant browsers, which I think is pretty much all of them at this point).

Comment: @Will: not IE, which has a quirky interpretation of the meaning of that attribute. And no, indeed that doesn't change the internal representation of the string; ECMAScript and the DOM both require operations to work on UTF-16 code units, so it's almost inevitably going to be UTF-16LE or BE internally. (In reality LE, though you don't really care.)